# asp net check if username exists C# procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, procedure, exists

I created the Procedure and added it to Load page, my code looks like that now:

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  CheckIfUserExists   
(    
    @UserName Varchar(50),  
    @IsExists INT OUTPUT   
)   
AS      

If exists (select Nazwa_uzytkownika from Uzytkownicy where Nazwa_uzytkownika = @UserName)   
Begin

Set @IsExists = 1

End     
Else   
begin

Set @IsExists = 0

End

Return @IsExists
```

**Code:**

```
namespace Komis_Samochodowy1
{
    public partial class Rejestracja : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConn"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckIfUserExists", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", un.Text);
            **int rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**    //Error

            if (rowAffected == 1)
            {
                status.Visible = true;
                status.Text = "Uzytkownik istnieje.";
            }
        }
        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("AboutMe.aspx");
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Offer.aspx");
        }

        protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
        }

        protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConn"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string dodajQuery = "insert into Uzytkownicy (Nazwa_uzytkownika, Kraj, Hasło, Email) values (@Unazwa, @ukraj, @uhasło, @uemail) ";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(dodajQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unazwa", un.Text.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ukraj", country.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uhasło", pass.Text.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uemail", email.Text.ToString());
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            Response.Write("Rejestracja zakonczona.");
            conn.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

Still doesn't work at all, it crush every time on bolted part, what i did wrong?

Additional information: Procedure or function 'CheckIfUserExists' expects parameter '@IsExists', which was not supplied.

Comment: Apart from your problem - you don't close the `conn`. Use either `conn.Close()` or (better) `using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConn"].ConnectionString) { /* your code here */  }`. And even if it is a great language, you should still avoid writing function names in Polish ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", un.Text);
var outparam = new SqlParameter("@IsExist", SqlDbType.Int);
outparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outparam);
int rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if ((int)outparam.Value == 1)
{
    // user exists
}
else
{
    // user does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you the problem. You need to add a parameter called `IsExists` with `.Direction` set to `ParameterDirection.Output` or `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`, and then check the `.Value` of that parameter **after** you have executed the command. As a side note, you could also check the return value, but you would **still** need to add a parameter called `IsExists`, and **separately** add a parameter with direction `ReturnValue`, so that would actually make more work.

It is a **lot** easier to use sql methods that `select` the result, rather than `return` the result or use `output` parameters. Then you could just use `ExecuteScalar`.

Note that the return value from `ExecuteNonQuery` is **not** the same thing as the return value from the query. Yes, that sounds odd.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", un.Text);
var isExists = cmd.Parameters.Add("IsExists", SqlDbType.Int);
isExists.Value = DBNull.Value;
isExists.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
bool exists = (int)isExists.Value == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to add the output parameter and direction which is missing, kindly try this. I've not checked the syntax:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsExists", SqlDbType.bool);
    cmd.Parameters["@IsExists"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```